# Problems with extremum of two uniform random variables

Tags: self-study, random-variable, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Here is the problem from the book:

> Let $X = \min(U,V)$ and $Y = \max(U,V)$ for independent $\text{uniform}(0,1)$ variables $U$ and $V$.  Find the distributions of a) $X$; b) $1-Y$; c) $Y-X$.

I know that each has density $2(1-x)$ for $0<x<1$.  What I'm hoping for is an intuitive explanation of how to understand this problem and arrive at that solution without knowing the beta distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explanation for the result that $X$, $1-Y$, and $Y-X$ have the same distribution in this case is as follows.

First, consider a plane with coordinate axes $u$ and $v$ and let 
$(U,V)$ be a random point in the plane chosen according to some 
joint density function $f_{U,V}(u,v)$.  $U$ and $V$ need not be 
independent random variables.  Then,
$$\begin{align*}
P\{X > \alpha\} &= P\{\min(U,V) > \alpha\} = P\{U > \alpha, V > \alpha\},\\
P\{1-Y > \alpha\} &= P\{1-\max(U,V) > \alpha\} = P\{\max(U,V) < 1 - \alpha\}\\
&= P\{U < 1- \alpha, V < 1- \alpha\},\\
P\{Y-X > \alpha\} &= P\{\max(U,V)-\min(U,V) > \alpha\}\\
&= P\{U-V > \alpha\} + P\{V-U > \alpha\}.
\end{align*}$$
These three probabilities  can be found in the general case by
integrating $f_{U,V}(u,v)$ over the appropriate region which can be 
described in the three cases respectively as

- the *northeast quadrant* of the plane with *southwest corner* 
  $(\alpha, \alpha)$
- the *southwest quadrant* of the plane with *northeast corner* 
  $(1-\alpha, 1-\alpha)$
- the half-plane *below* the line $v < u - \alpha$ and the half-plane *above* the line $v > u + \alpha$

So much for generalities.  If the random point $(U,V)$ is *uniformly
distributed* on a *region* $A$ of the plane (that is,
$f_{U,V}(u,v)$ is nonzero and constant for $(u,v) \in A$,
$f_{U,V}(u,v) = 0$ for $(u,v) \notin A$) and $B$ is any
region of the plane, then
$$P\{(U,V) \in B\} = P\{(U,V) \in A\cap B\} 
= \frac{\mathrm{Area}(A\cap B)}{\mathrm{Area}(A)}.$$
In particular, if we can compute areas via mensuration
formulas learned in school, we do not need to integrate
formally.

Finally, in the special case when $A$ is the *unit-area* square with
opposite corners $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, and $\alpha$ is a number between
$0$ and $1$,
$$\begin{align*}
P\{X > \alpha\} &= P\{U > \alpha, V > \alpha\}\\
&= P\{(U,V) \in ~\mathrm{square~with~opposite~corners}~ (\alpha,\alpha)
~ \mathrm{and}~ (1,1)\\
&= (1-\alpha)^2,\\
P\{1-Y > \alpha\} &= P\{U < 1- \alpha, V < 1- \alpha\}\\
&= P\{(U,V) \in ~\mathrm{square~with~opposite~corners}~ (0,0)
~ \mathrm{and}(1-\alpha,1-\alpha)~ \\
&= (1-\alpha)^2,\\
P\{Y-X > \alpha\} &= P\{U-V > \alpha\} + P\{V-U > \alpha\}\\
&= P\{(U,V) \in ~\mathrm{triangle~with~corners}~ (\alpha,0),
(1,1-\alpha) ~\mathrm{and}~(1,0)\}\\
&\quad \quad 
+ P\{(U,V) \in ~\mathrm{triangle~with~corners}~ (0,\alpha),
(1-\alpha,1) ~\mathrm{and}~(0,1)\}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(1-\alpha)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(1-\alpha)^2 = (1-\alpha)^2.\\
\end{align*}$$
So the *complementary* cumulative distribution of the three
random variables $X$, $1-Y$ and $Y-X$ is the same $(1-\alpha)^2$
in this case,
and so the three random variables have the same density function
$2(1-\alpha)$, $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll work out the first one and leave the other two to you. First, find $\Pr(X \leq x)$. We have
$$\begin{align*}\Pr(X \leq x) &= 1 - \Pr(X > x) \\
&= 1 - \Pr(U > x, V > x) \\ &= 1 - \Pr(U > x)\Pr(V > x) \\ &= 1 - (1-x)^2 \end{align*}$$
The first step follows that, for $x$ to be a minimum $U$ and $V$ must be greater than that value. Independence gives us the second line. Use of the CDF of the uniform gives us the third.

To get the density, take the derivative to get $2(1-x)$.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie.  You were actually the head GSI for my Econ 140 class.  I've always found your explanations to be very clear and precise.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $P(X \geq x)$ in the first line?

Comment: @mark999, you're right, that was a typo. I actually rewrote it to be clearer. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @GlendonTrullinger, Glad that I could be of help. Sorry for the typo in the first draft.

Comment: For the third case on $Y-X$, you have to get the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ first, as $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.